# How to run the feature file for definite number for times in karate framework?

Tags: cucumber, karate

Example: I need to post the payment for an account for 100 times with same set data .
In that case how to iterate the particular feature file using karate framework.
Please help on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a performance testing tool instead of Karate.

But still, if you insist, here is the best reference example [`call-dynamic-json.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/calldynamic/call-dynamic-json.feature).

Also make sure you read the section on [data-driven features](https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features) in the documentation. All the best !

Comment: Please let me know if we can pass the count variable to the feature file as an parameter or arguments?

Comment: Is there any way to call feature file from the java code apart from using @cucumberOptions annotations ?

Comment: Thanks a lot . It worked but unable to get karate html report

Comment: of course. the java api is not for testing. you seem to be REALLY confused.