# How to iterate the excel rows for specific feature file using karate framework?

Tags: cucumber, karate

I have an excelUtility class to read values the excel.How to iterate the excel values and call the feature file from java code .
Please help on this issue.

Comment: I'm intrigued, in the last few days I've seen a lot of questions related to the Karate framework and I can't remember having seen too many before that. What's the sudden interest? Ah, they've just learned to add the Java tag to the questions recently.

Comment: Kayaman - didn't notice ! I'll try remove the java tag where applicable

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is not a Karate question.

But a hint - if you figure out how to return a Java `List` from your Excel utility, you are all set. Refer to the `dogs.feature` in the demo examples.

And refer to this answer also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48079061/143475